# Add single index data frame to multi index data frame, Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to add single data frame to multi index data frame?
for example

my multi index data is

```
                Name  Code  Buying_Date  Buying_Price  Buying_Qty  

Date     Code                                                      
20140117 none   a   1234          20170101           5         7   
20170120 none   b   5678          20180101           6         8
```

and i desire to add following data to 'Date' = '20170120'

```
                Name  Code  Buying_Date  Buying_Price  Buying_Qty  

  Code                                                      
  abcd           af   abcd   20170101           5         7   
  efgh           bf   efgh   20180101           6         8
```

desire result is

```
               Name  Code  Buying_Date  Buying_Price  Buying_Qty  

Date     Code                                                      
20140117 none   a   1234          20170101           5         7   
20170120 none   b   5678          20180101           6         8  
         abcd   af  abcd          20170101           5         7   
         efgh   bf  efgh          20180101           6         8
```

thanks your advise in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = df1.append(df2.assign(Date=20170120).set_index('Date', append=True).swaplevel(0,1))
print (df)
               Buying_Date  Buying_Price  Buying_Qty  Code  Code.1 Name
Date     Code                                                          
20140117 none     20170101             5           7   NaN  1234.0    a
20170120 none     20180101             6           8   NaN  5678.0    b
         abcd     20170101             5           7  abcd     NaN   af
         efgh     20180101             6           8  efgh     NaN   bf
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.assign(Date=20170120).set_index('Date', append=True).swaplevel(0,1))
              Name  Code  Buying_Date  Buying_Price  Buying_Qty
Date     Code                                                  
20170120 abcd   af  abcd     20170101             5           7
         efgh   bf  efgh     20180101             6           8
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) new column and add to `index` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
2. `swaplevel` of levels in `MultiIndex`
3. Last [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to first `DataFrame`