# Adding a Dataframe to a multindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a historical time-series of a number of identifiers for a number of different metrics, as part of that i'm trying to create multi index dataframe and then "fill it" with the individual dataframes.

Multi Index:

```
                   ID1                 ID2
             ITEM1      ITEM2     ITEM1      ITEM2 
index
```

Dataframe to insert

```
      ITEM1        ITEM2 
Date

a
b
c
```

looking through the official docs and this website i found the following relevant: 
[Add single index data frame to multi index data frame, Pandas, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395427/add-single-index-data-frame-to-multi-index-data-frame-pandas-python) and the associated pandas official docs pages: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

i've managed with something like :

```
for i in df1.index: 
for j in df2.columns:
    df1.loc[i,(ID,j)]=df2.loc[i,j]
```

but it seems highly inefficient when i need to do this across circa 100 dataframes.

for some reason a simply

```
df1.loc[i,(ID)]=df2.loc[i] doesn't seem to work
```

neither does :

```
df1[ID1]=df1.append(df2)
```

which returns a Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series 
my understanding from looking around is that this is because im effectively leaving half the dataframe empty ( ragged list? )

any help appreciated on how to iteratively populate my multi index DF would be greatly appreciated.

let me know if i've missed relevant information,

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Setup

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] * 2] * 3,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['ID1 ID2 ID3'.split(), range(4)])
)

df2 = df1.ID1 * 2
```

---

```
df1

  ID1          ID2          ID3         
    0  1  2  3   0  1  2  3   0  1  2  3
0   1  2  3  4   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
1   1  2  3  4   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
2   1  2  3  4   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
```

---

```
df2

    0  1  2  3
0   2  4  6  8
1   2  4  6  8
2   2  4  6  8
```

---

The problem is that Pandas is trying to line up indices (or columns in this case).  We can do some transpose/join trickery but I'd rather avoid that.

### Option 1

Take advantage of the fact that we can assign via `loc` an array so long as the shape matches up.  Well, we better make sure it does and that the order of columns and index are correct.  I use `align` with the `right` parameter to do this.  Then assign the values of the aligned `df2`

```
df1.loc[:, 'ID1'] = df2.align(df1.ID1, 'right')[0].values
df1

  ID1          ID2          ID3         
    0  1  2  3   0  1  2  3   0  1  2  3
0   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
1   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
2   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
```

---

### Option 2

Or, we can give `df2` the additional level of column indexing that we need to lined it up.  The use `update` to replace the relevant cells in place.

```
df1.update(pd.concat({'ID1': df2}, axis=1))
df1

  ID1          ID2          ID3         
    0  1  2  3   0  1  2  3   0  1  2  3
0   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
1   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
2   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
```

---

### Option 3

A creative way using `stack` and `assign` with `unstack`

```
df1.stack().assign(ID1=df2.stack()).unstack()

  ID1          ID2          ID3         
    0  1  2  3   0  1  2  3   0  1  2  3
0   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
1   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
2   2  4  6  8   5  6  1  2   3  4  5  6
```

Comment: Hi @piRSquared, forget my previous comment, found a neat way to implement your update concat suggestion. 
This worked and is easily iterated to populate my dataframe, now onto finding a way to ensure indices align ! 
thanks again for the prompt help!


`import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['ID1 ID2 ID3'.split(), range(4)])
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4]]*3,columns=range(4))

df1=df1.append(pd.concat({'ID1': df2}, axis=1))`
PS: apologies for the horrible formatting, being new to stackoverflow, i'm a bit clumsy.